# Can I use any USB flash drive to install firmware updates on a PS3?

Tags: ps3

I want to install `PS3UPDAT.PUP` on my new PS3 hard drive, I wanted to find out if  I can use any USB flash drive for installation?

Last time I used a Kingston USB flash drive and the console couldn't read the USB drive.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Update your Ps3?

Comment: PS3's can only read FAT32 drives.  Since most computers from Windows 7 on up use NTFS, you'll have to specifically format the drive as FAT32 in order to get the PS3 to read it.

Comment: Are you asking if it is possible AT ALL to install firmware from a flash drive, or if **any brand of flash drive** will work?

Answer (score 1):

First you'll need a 32GB or smaller USB drive. Then use one of the many free FAT32 USB drive formatting tools available to format the drive to FAT32. From there make sure you create the correct directory structure (as indicated on Sony's firmware download page) for placement of the firmware file, and that's it.